# Modifying an interactive map in R Studio

Tags: leaflet, rstudio, shapefile, interactive

I'm trying to create an interactive map using leaftlet in R studio. The issue is, I want to modify the polygons or maybe add this image to the map.So, in the interactive map of the USA, I want to see this map in it.

I've see online on using shapefiles, and geosjon but I don't have enough experience with it. Also, image overlay didn't for me.